# JTextArea Autoresizing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I have a textarea inside a scrollpane that's initially editable so the user can put in input. When they click a button, it grabs this input and sets the area to be uneditable. However, whenever it changes state from editable to noneditable, if it had more text than the area could handle without scrollbars, it resizes the area to fit all the text, messing up the rest of the UI. How would I force it to stick to the size it starts as?
This is the relevant code:

```
txtrTag = new JTextArea();
txtrTag.setEditable(true);
txtrTag.setOpaque(true);

JScrollPane txtrTagScrollPane = new JScrollPane(txtrTag);

private void doTrack(ActionEvent e){
    if (bTracking == false){
        txtrTag.setEditable(false);
        txtrTag.setOpaque(false);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a text area the code should be something like:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
```

The rows/columns values will allow the text area to determine a preferred size for itself. So when you add the text area to the scrollpane the scrollpane will be sized appropriately.

Then the editable state should not have an impact on the preferred size.